# Обособление оборота с А

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

Не очень понимаю до сих пор, когда этот оборот закрывается, а когда отношения как при однородных членах.

Возьмём такой пример:

> *Он кому-то привозит подарки, а кому-то нет(,) каждый раз, как возвращается домой.*

Буду рад и общим советам, как разбираться в каждом конкретном случае с такими оборотами.

Comment: В вашем предложении запятая действительно не ставится,  но его стилистика не очень удачная. Возможное редактирование:  Каждый раз он кому-то привозит подарки, а кому-то нет, когда возвращается домой.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon, но я специально составил его именно так, чтобы вопрос о закрытии оборота был актуален. В вашем ведь случае его конец совпадает с началом придаточного и запятую нельзя не поставить.

Comment: Пожалуйста, Артем.  Ваше редакция этого предложения выглядела довольно очевидно.  Дело в том, что в реальности предложения "с продолжением" встречаются не очень часто.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, здесь действует следующее правило:

> После последнего однородного члена предложения, присоединяемого
> противительным или подчинительным союзом и не заканчивающего собой
> предложения, запятая не ставится (т. е. последний однородный член не
> обособляется): ...*Каждый вечер
> солнце садилось в море, а не в тучи и было при этом клюквенного цвета*
> (Ю. К.)

То есть запятая не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо, Nektoid!

Comment: Nektoid, уточняющий оборот вроде бы положено закрывать.

Comment: @ЕгорСальков это не уточняющий оборот. Хотя бы потому, что нет сужения понятия.

Answer (score 0):

Артём, какие могут быть "отношения как при однородных членах", если союз ***а*** — всегда **противительный** союз? *По утрам я пью кофе, **а** не чай. По календарю было начало лета, **а** теплее на улице не стало.*

А что касается любого оборота, то он не имеет никакого отношения к однородным членам и закрывается **всегда** (если уж открылся).

Comment: Предлагаю вам открыть справочник Розенталя (раздел "Пунктуация") и прочитать § 12 пункт 5: *"Между однородными членами предложения, соединенными посредством противительных союзов а, но, да (в значении ‘но’), однако, зато и др..."* -- и далее.